# Change the label of Element\Text in ZF2

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, label

I am trying to change the label of text input in a ZF2 Form, but doesn't succeed to change it.
I try several things such as :

```
$this->get('MyField')->setLabel('my new label');
$this->get('MyField')->setOption('label','my new label');
$this->get('MyField')->setOptions(array('label' => 'my new label'));
```

It is like get return something that is on read only.

Comment: It depends the structure of your form ... Do you use fieldset ? In which method do you try to change the label ?

Comment: Can you post more code? Show how you set up the form and the context of where you're using it.